# Store MKPolygon in Realm database

Tags: json, swift, mapkit, realm, geojson

I'm developing an iOS app in Swift that fetches some data from a remote HTTP server and shows some features on a map. As these features don't change frequently I thought I would be a good idea to keep a local cache of the data (that can be displayed even in offline conditions) and only update it in the background.
I'm using MapKit to display the map and the data is fetched as JSON.

I thought to use Realm for this local cache (please feel free to suggest any other solution and/or approach if they better fit this scenario).

---

The data I get from the server is geoJSON and the `Feature` geometry looks like this:

```
{
  "type" : "Feature", 
  "geometry" : 
  {
    "type" : "Polygon", 
    "coordinates" : 
    [
      [
        [15.7008834173655, 34.4622385876223], 
        [15.7453028366596, 34.4356537554745], 
        [15.7759359455856, 34.3953785537464], 
        //....
      ]
    ]
  }
{
```

Every `Area` boundary polygon usually has a few hundreds of points.

---

The model object I need to cache might look something like this:

```
class Area: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var description: String?

    var boundary: MKPolygon! //as a MKPolygon to be drawn on map
    //OR:
    var boundary: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [] //as an array of coordinate structs
    //OR:
    var boundary: [[Double]] = [] //as a 2D array of coordinates (as in geoJSON)


    //OR (only working solution):
    var geoJSON: String = "" //store the geoJSON data directly as String

}
```

The `boundary` property will be used to draw the `Area` on a map as a MKPolygon.

---

Obviously of the examples above only storing the geoJSON data works with Realm, but I wanted to know what the *"right way to do it"* is. I like Realm ease of use, but I don't think it's a good idea to store everything as Realm Objects as that would mean creating a huge number of `Point` objects just to draw a single Polygon.

Thanks, any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Realm doesn't support storing `MKPolygon` etc, you can find the list of supported property types in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types).

I think you have two options here as you said:

1. Create a `Point` object and store it as a to-many relationship, and it's definitely not a bad idea :)
2. Serialize coordinates to `String` or `Data` object and store it in database, like you do it right now.